# Jupyter Notebook download without save

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, miniconda

I want to ask a question.

Yesterday I was taking a ML exam and we were using Jupyter Notebook. I needed to download the file and send it to my teacher.
Because I was in a rush, I just clicked download without saving the file. Mind you, I was writing this file for about an hour.

Now I am worried if the code I was writing was saved and if the teacher can see it.

Does Jupyter Notebook have autosave?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

yes jupyter is autosave don't worry whenever you write code and run using shift enter then it will auto-save

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).